# Updating javascript Array inside object updates all arrays in the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think I am having a bit of a stupid moment here, so hoping you can help.

I have an object `discount_arr` which holds an associative array of numbers. When trying to update a specific array though, it seems to apply to all the arrays in the object.

Both of these update all the items which is not what I want.

`discount_arr.EMAILVIP[0] = 100;`

`discount_arr[EMAILVIP][0] = 100;`

[image]

I am sure I am missing something really obvious...

EDIT:

To populate the object I use this code: This loops through another set of data to only pull through unique codes which are used as the array item itself.

`var default_days = [];` is an array of defaults which I am looking to overwrite. I populate it with a number of 0 values based on days in the month.

```
  var unique = {};
    for( var i in data ){

        //console.log(data[i]);

        for (var j in data[i]){

            //console.log(j);

            if( typeof(unique[j]) === "undefined"){
                discount_arr[j] = default_days;
            }
            unique[j] = 0;

        }

    }
```

Comment: That code should work. Are you doing this in a loop?

Comment: Can you show the code where your are doing those updates?

Comment: How are you polulating / initializing these arrays? Can you share that part of the code?

Comment: I was doing it inside a loop but to sanity check, that screenshot is by just trying to update the EMAILVIP array. For some reason though, it updates every array item 0 in the entire object. No idea why.

Comment: The problem might be that all the arrays are referencing the same array in the memory. So, if you can share how you're populating the array's we might be able to help

Comment: It may happen if your all arrays point to the same object. Are you copying array [0, ...., 0] from the same source?

Comment: Yeah, I am actually `default_days` is the same array that I am copying as a set of defaults. Updated the question with the other code.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that those statement are not equal. `discount_arr[EMAILVIP][0] = 100` should be `discount_arr['EMAILVIP'][0] = 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all of your arrays refer to the same `default_days` array.

Use `discount_arr[j] = [...default_days];` instead to copy array

If you're not using ES6, then 
`discount_arr[j] = default_days.concat();` should do it

Comment: Oh wow, I did not realise JS did that, bloody hell ha. I am guessing the ... tells JS to copy the array instead of referencing it?

Comment: You can also use `discount_arr[j] = default_days.slice(0)`, which is faster than using the spread syntax (benchmark : https://jsperf.com/cloning-arrays/3)

Comment: Something to remember when doing JS in the future!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, really love this place! Great group of people.